# Excel compare cell in different rows based on group of a specific column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet has data for example.

| SerialNumber | Key | AckAt | ReturnAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sn1 | key1 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-02 |
| sn1 | key2 | 2022-03-01 | N/A |
| sn2 | key3 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-01 |
| sn3 | key4 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-01 |
| sn3 | key5 | 2022-03-02 | N/A |

What I'm trying to achieve is creating a new column that
If a serial number has more than one key and the 2nd key is Act before the 1st key Return, the column will show true, otherwise, show false. Like below

| SerialNumber | Key | AckAt | ReturnAt | bool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sn1 | key1 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-02 | true |
| sn1 | key2 | 2022-03-01 | N/A | N/A |
| sn2 | key3 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-01 | N/A |
| sn3 | key4 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-01 | false |
| sn3 | key5 | 2022-03-02 | N/A | N/A |

I hope there is sort of formula or feature that can achieve this but my experience of excel is quite limited that I don't even know where to begin with.

Comment: last I checked 2022 is not a leap year and as such there is no `2022-02-29`

Comment: Right, haha, my brain was like blank while typing those sample, but you can get my point right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to first test if the ReturnAt is `N/A` or the only key for that SerialNumber.

Then we will test if the dates are earlier or not:

```
=IF(OR(D2="N/A",COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)=0),"N/A",COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2,C:C,"<"&D2)>0)
```

[image]

Comment: Need more time to understand the formula but it works for my data, thanks